# not able to pass authentication of wordpress api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have written the below code to fetch my posts from the WordPress.

```
import fetch, { Headers } from "node-fetch"
const headers = new Headers()


const ourPassword = "applicationPassword"
const ourUsername = "username"

headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + Buffer.from(`${ourUsername}:${ourPassword}`).toString("base64"))

try{
const response = await fetch("http://mywebsite/wp-json/wp/v2/help?page=3", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: headers})

console.log(await response.json())
}catch(e){
  console.log("error",e)
}
```

I get error the below error:

```
{'code': 'rest_cannot_access', 'message': 'DRA: Only authenticated users can access the REST API.', 'data': {'status': 401}}
```

I am sure my password and username are correct and there is no problem there. I am using the application password which I generated for my user.

Comment: I was using the wrong application passwotd. I was using authentication password.